# Elasticsearch create an index that includes a field of type long with an initial value

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query for creating an index called highlighttest2. It works fine, except for the spec_label. I am trying to create it as a long (rather than the default text) and, ideally, have it initialized as 1.  The below is not working correctly. Grateful for the proper syntax. Thanks.

```
POST /highlighttest2/_doc/1
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Reference": "2012-01-01",
  "Title": "Sales Manager",
  "Description": "We are looking for an organized Project Administrator to perform Commercial duties on projects. The Project Administrator is responsible for scheduling meetings, managing office inventory, and tracking expenses. To be successful as a Project Administrator you must be able to multitask. A good Project Administrator has excellent attention to detail.",
  "DescriptionHtml": "<section><p>We are looking for an organized Project Administrator to perform clerical duties on projects.</p> <p>The Project Administrator is responsible for scheduling meetings, managing office inventory, and tracking expenses. To be successful as a Project Administrator you must be able to multitask.</p> <p>A good Project Administrator has excellent attention to detail.</p></section>",
  "Organisation": "US4",
  "myNested":{"spec_label":{"type": "long"}}
```

}

Comment: The command you show is not for creating an index, but for creating a specific document. You're mixing data (Id, Reference, etc) and mapping (myNested)

Comment: @Val yes, I understand that I am creating an index with a a document with a particular structure. Maybe I should have asked how to create any index with a field that is of type long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create an index containing a specific mapping, you first need to create it explicitly by providing the [mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html) you want, as shown below:

```
PUT highlighttest2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "Id": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "Reference": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      ...
      "myNested":{
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
           "spec_label":{
              "type": "long"
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then only you can index your documents with concrete data

```
POST /highlighttest2/_doc/1
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Reference": "2012-01-01",
  "Title": "Sales Manager",
  "Description": "We are looking for an organized Project Administrator to perform Commercial duties on projects. The Project Administrator is responsible for scheduling meetings, managing office inventory, and tracking expenses. To be successful as a Project Administrator you must be able to multitask. A good Project Administrator has excellent attention to detail.",
  "DescriptionHtml": "<section><p>We are looking for an organized Project Administrator to perform clerical duties on projects.</p> <p>The Project Administrator is responsible for scheduling meetings, managing office inventory, and tracking expenses. To be successful as a Project Administrator you must be able to multitask.</p> <p>A good Project Administrator has excellent attention to detail.</p></section>",
  "Organisation": "US4",
  "myNested":{
     "spec_label": 12353672
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Val. This is exactly how I should have done this. Thanks

Comment: Awesome, glad it worked!